# How to use wait_for command in the 'on message' event discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot have the same functionality as an 
`input()`command, but as discord.py rewrite didn't have that command, I searched the API and found `wait_for`. But, of course, it brought a whole load of problems with it. I searched the internet for this, but most of the answers were in a `@command.command` and not `async def on_message(message)` and the others weren't really helpful. the furthest I got was:

````
def check(m):
    if m.author.name == message.author.name and m.channel.name == message.channel.name:
        return True
    else:
        return False
msg = "404 file not found"
try:
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=60)
await message.channel.send(msg)
except TimeoutError:
    await message.channel.send("timed out. try again.")
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    pass

    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're using the same variable `msg` for multiple things. Here is a working example I can make with the information you've given.

```py
msg = "404 file not found"
await message.channel.send(msg)

def check(m):
    return m.author == message.author and m.channel == message.channel

try:
    mesg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=60)
except TimeoutError: # The only error this can raise is an asyncio.TimeoutError
    return await message.channel.send("Timed out, try again.")
await message.channel.send(mesg.content) # mesg.content is the response, do whatever you want with this
```

mesg returns a [message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message) object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: FYI: The "404 file not found" was just a placeholder for msg. Thanks for your answer!